# Класс множество

Tags: c++

Насколько я понимаю в множестве содержатся не повторяющиеся элементы.
Т.к. их количество переменное - значит имеет смысл хранить элементы в списке.

Где правильнее объявить описание списка? внутри класса или снаружи?

Поправьте меня, если пишу бред.

Comment: нужно изобрести std::set?

Comment: да) надо сделать велосипед) второе задание аналогично, но там упорядоченное множество, не думаю, что труднее, просто там будут места оптимизации и несколько другой код. пока размышляю над скелетом класса.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Логичное решение:

1. Класс множество
2. Класс элемент
3. Класс множество управляет элементами, в частности списком).

Comment: получается что список должен иметь свои функции вывода? или может просто объявить структуру?

Comment: Надо смотреть на задачу. Если множество конкретных элементов ( даблы или строки и т.д.) то логично у элемента множества сделать ввод и вывод.
А если на шаблонах - то тоже самое, сделать свой ввод и вывод, но там уже интереснее.

Comment: Хм... а может ли иметь смысл написать как расширение для класса связанного списка?

Comment: Делайте через хэш-таблицу. Коллизии разрешайте списками.

Answer (score 1):

> Т.к. их количество переменное - значит
> имеет смысл хранить элементы в списке

А почему не в дереве или не в массиве?

> Где правильнее объявить описание
> списка? внутри класса или снаружи?

Правильнее объявить в зависимости от того, нужно ли пользователю знать о классе списка или нет. Если планируется использование класса-списка отдельно, то нужно объявлять вне, если нет, то внутри.